# Refund laws in europe and austrailia

Tags: mit

I distribute my software for free, under the MIT licence.  This says there is no warranty, but in some jurisdictions there is a mandatory warranty

- https://www.accc.gov.au/business/treating-customers-fairly/offering-warranties/warranties-against-defects#warranties-against-defects
- https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/shopping/guarantees-returns/index_en.htm.

Under these laws can I issue a $0 refund?

Comment: To whom would you issue such a refund?  Someone who downloaded your MIT-licensed software without paying then complained it wasn't working?

Comment: Yes.What to do.$0 refund?

Comment: That's what they paid, so yes. Do you have any reason to think it wouldn't satisfy the requirements?

Comment: I mean do I have to write some kind of a disclaimer over the Mit lisence.

Comment: If that's what you mean, why didn't you ask it?  What sort of disclaimer did you have in mind?

Comment: Given that the license grants you no warranty over what is legally required, and that you don't charge anything - on what damages do you think you could be sued? IMHO you are safe as you don't sell, thus don't work commercially. Mandatory warranty as by those terms only applies to business to consumer interactions in EU.

Comment: The damages include cost to buy internet to download.

Answer (score 1):

Under those warranty laws, you are required to repair or replace faulty goods or you must give a (partial or full) refund if the goods turn out to be irreparable.

First of all, those laws refer to goods, as in primarily physical products. I am not sure to what extent a software-only product is actually covered by those laws. (Edit: Based on the comments, it appears they are.)

Assuming that software-only products do fall under those laws, then they would first require you to fix any bugs that are reported by consumers and to provide the fixed version to those consumers at no cost. As your product is already zero cost, your compliance to the law would be met if you take bug reports seriously and give feedback about updated versions. You would be fulfilling your obligations by replacing the faulty product with a repaired one.

Comment: However the user incurs cost in downloading the app internet.

Comment: The user also incurs a cost in driving to the shop. That is also not refunded if the product is defective.

Comment: Are you absolutely most sure?Isn't a transportation cost?

Comment: Yes, Bart van I gen Schenau is right. You don't get reimbursed your way to the shop either

Comment: "I am not sure to what extent a software-only product is actually covered by those laws." It's definitely covered by the laws in Australia. Valve got fined millions of dollars by the ACCC, which is why there's a refund option on Steam now.